# Filtering elements, if no results display this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am filtering out some elements based on what is in their data-attribute and I want to display some HTML if there are no results. I'm not very knowledgeable about JS/jQuery so I can't quite think through how to accomplish that. I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#filter").keyup(function() {
    var selectSize = $(this).val();
    filter(selectSize);
});
function filter(e) {
    var numVisible = 0;
    var addCard = $('.ourTeamCards');
    if(e) {
        var regex = new RegExp('\\b\\w*' + e + '\\w*\\b', 'i');
        $('.oneStaff').fadeOut(50).filter(function () {
            var regExists = regex.test($(this).data('regions'));
            if(regExists) {
                numVisible +=1; 
            }
            return regExists;
        }).fadeIn(50);
    } else {
        $('.oneStaff').fadeIn(50);
    }
    if(numVisible == 0) {
        addCard.append("<div class='noResults'>No Results</div>");
    }
    else {
        $('.noResults').css('display', 'none');
    }
}
```

Here is a pen with a working example: https://codepen.io/west4me/pen/dQZxMZ
If you search for Wyoming you will see it filter. If you search for Washington you wont get any results. If there are no results I would like to append some HTML/Text saying there are no results.

Comment: Create a working example (snippet) with the relevant code so it will be possible to understand what you are doing and what is the issue.

Comment: @Dekel I added a Codepen with a working example.

Comment: and where is your code that in charge of displaying "there are no results"?

Comment: @Dekel That's what I am trying to figure out how to add. I added some HTML with display:none, not sure if that is what you are looking for or not.

Comment: ok, so you added that element and it's hidden. I don't see any attempt to display it.

Comment: @Dekel If you notice, this question is about how to show it if there are no results. I do not know how to do that. I can't add it if I do not know how. Is my question not clear enough?

Comment: Did you try to search google for jquery show/hide elements?

Comment: Yes I did a search.

Comment: great, update your findings on the question

Comment: I've updated the jQuery and codepen with what I have figured out so far. I have it almost working. I have the element added when there is no result. It is also removed when you delete the characters that didn't produce a result. However if you search and there are no results and keep typing, the message is appended again and again.

Comment: You `addCard.append` every time you run the `filter` function - so this will be appended multiple times. Instead of append it - juse change the visibility (using the `css('display'...)` or the `show/hide` functions.

Comment: I got it working. Not sure it is the best way to do it but it's working. See codepen.

Comment: Nice :) it's great!

Comment: Noticed one issue still, Say you are searching for Texas, you start typing and make a type, Texaq. No results is displayed. Now if you backspace through it all and end up with an empty field, the no results is displayed again.

Comment: So display the "no result" only if the string is not empty.

Comment: Got it figured out. Codepen is up to date now.

Comment: Got my vote on both question and answer for the time you took to solve this yourself. Great job! :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out. Here is the code that worked for me:

```js
$("#filter").keyup(function() {
 var selectSize = $(this).val();
 filter(selectSize);
});
function filter(e) {
 var numVisible = 0;
 var addCard = $('.ourTeamCards');
 if(e) {
  var regex = new RegExp('\\b\\w*' + e + '\\w*\\b', 'i');
  $('.oneStaff').fadeOut(50).filter(function () {
   var regExists = regex.test($(this).data('regions'));
   if(regExists) {
    numVisible +=1; 
   }
   return regExists;
  }).fadeIn(50);
  if (numVisible == 0) {
   $('.noResults').css('display', 'block'); 
  }
   else {
   $('.noResults').css('display', 'none');
  }
 } 
 else {
  $('.oneStaff').fadeIn(50);
 } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="filterSearch">
        <h1 class="">Filter</h1>        
          <input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control quicksearch" placeholder="Search">
        <span class="d-block mt-2 searchIns">Search by country or state</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row ourTeamCards">
    <div class="oneStaff col-4 border border-primary" data-target="#exampleModal" data-regions="Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Hawaii, Idaho, Kansas, Louisiana, Missouri, Montana, Nebraska, Nevada, New Mexico, North Dakota, Oklahoma, Oregon, South Dakota, Texas, Utah, Wyoming">
    Name
    </div>
<div class="oneStaff col-4 border border-primary" data-target="#exampleModal" data-regions="Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Hawaii, Idaho, Kansas, Louisiana, Missouri, Montana, Nebraska, Nevada, New Mexico, North Dakota, Oklahoma, Oregon, South Dakota, Texas, Utah">
    Name
    </div>
<div class="oneStaff col-4 border border-primary" data-target="#exampleModal" data-regions="Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Hawaii, Idaho, Kansas, Louisiana, Missouri, Montana, Nebraska, Nevada, New Mexico, North Dakota, Oklahoma, Oregon, South Dakota, Texas, Utah">
    Name
    </div>    
  </div>
<div class="noResults" style="display:none;">No Results</div>
```